# Reset Password URL in Angular/Django

Tags: angularjs, django, url, forgot-password

I have a Django web application, with an Angular front end. On my sign in page, I have a forgot password link that takes you to a form where you enter in your email. This will send out an email with a reset url. The crux of the problem is that when a user clicks on that link they receive in an email, or copy/paste it into a web browser, it tries to look for a Django url first, before it looks for an angular route. Once the app taps into the angular javascript the url will than work, but if just going straight to that link from the email like it is intended for, it does not work because there is no Django url for it, and Angular hasn't been touched yet. I hope that makes sense. For example here is what the url will look like

`http://domain-name/dportal/#/reset_password/d7/4oe-0f63050ac947ba024563`

Django URLs app tries first

```
# Webapp Urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dportal/', include('dealer_portal.urls')),
    url(r'^views/(?P<page_name>[-\w]+.html)/?$', webapp_views.angular_views),
    url(r'^simple_page/(?P<page_name>[-\w]+.html)/?$', webapp_views.simple_page),
    url(r'^home/', webapp_views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.ajax_urls')),
    url(r'^vehicle/', include('vehicle.ajax_urls')),
    url(r'^messages/', include('messaging.ajax_urls')),
    url(r'^dealer/', include('dealer.ajax_urls')),

    url(r'^api/homenet/test/', 'data_feed_homenet.views.test_conveyor_interface', name='api_homenet_test'),
    url(r'^api/homenet/', 'data_feed_homenet.views.conveyor_interface', name='api_homenet'),

    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social'))
]

# dealer_portal urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^views/(?P<page_name>[-\w]+.html)/?$', angular_views, name='angular_views'),
    url(r'^login', authenticate_user, name='auth_user'),
    url(r'^sign-out', sign_out, name='sign_out'),
    url(r'^getInventory', getVehicleInventory, name='get_inventory'),
    url(r'^dealer-threads', dealer_threads, name='dealer_threads'),
    url(r'^recent-messages', recent_messages, name='recent_messages'),
    url(r'^new-leads', new_leads, name='new_leads'),
    url(r'^assign-leads', assign_leads, name='assign_leads'),
    url(r'^get_customer/(?P<user_id>.*)/?$', get_customer, name='get_customer'),
    url(r'^get_employee/(?P<user_id>.*)/?$', get_employee, name='get_employees'),
    url(r'^add-employee', add_employee, name='add_employee'),
    url(r'^get-employees/', get_employees, name='get_employees'),
    url(r'^update-employees', update_employees, name='update_employees'),
    url(r'^delete-employees', delete_employees, name='delete_employees'),
    url(r'^create-thread', create_thread, name='create_thread'),
    url(r'^messages/(?P<thread_id>.*)/?$', get_messages, name='get_messages'),
    url(r'^new-message', new_message, name='new_message'),
    url(r'^get-user-selections/(?P<veh_id>.*)/?$', user_selections, name='user_selections'),
    url(r'^get-hours', get_hours, name='get_hours'),
    url(r'^save-hours', save_hours, name='save_hours'),
    url(r'^dealer', dealer_info, name='dealer_info'),
    url(r'^save-dealer-info', save_dealer, name='save_dealer'),
    url(r'^search-by-vin', search_by_vin, name='search_by_vin'),
    url(r'^save-holiday', save_holiday, name='save_holiday'),
    url(r'^.*$', portal_main, name='dealer_portal_home'),
]
```

Angular app configuration

```
/* eslint no-alert: 0 */

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('SocialAutoDealerPortalApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'mobile-angular-ui',
    'mobile-angular-ui.gestures',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'SocialAutoDealerPortalApp.controllers'
]);

app.run(function ($http, $transform, $rootScope, $window, $location, $route, SharedState) {
    console.log('App Running');
});

var portal_controllers = angular.module('SocialAutoDealerPortalApp.controllers', []);

// this allows our ajax requests to work with django by providing the security token
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/portal_home.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'portalHome'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/sign-in', {
        templateUrl: 'views/sign-in.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'dealer_signin'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/recover-pw', {
        templateUrl: 'views/forgot_password.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'passwordRecover'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/reset_password/:user/:reset_code', {
        templateUrl: 'views/reset_password.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'passwordReset'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/info', {
        templateUrl: 'views/info-hours.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'infoHours'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/inventory', {
        templateUrl: 'views/inventory.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'inventory'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/vehicle/:vid', {
        templateUrl: 'views/vehicle_userlist.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'vehicleSelections'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/user/:uid', {
        templateUrl: 'views/user_activitylist.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'portalProfile'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/employee/:uid', {
        templateUrl: 'views/employee_profile.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'portalEmployee'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/manage-employees', {
        templateUrl: 'views/manage_users.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'manageUsers'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/leads/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/threads.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'portalThreads'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/messages/:mid', {
        templateUrl: 'views/message.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        controller: 'portalChat'
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**
I changed my apps configuration, and if I copy/paste the url into the browser, it will work. If I just click on the link in the email however, it does not. It will go to the url, but than quickly redirect to the sign-in page.

Comment: The tag is wrong, it should be tagged in `angularjs` which is angular 1, just `angular` represent angular 2 or angular 4. update the tag, so you can get more audience for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip malik